# thresholding an image with bright zones

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, image-processing, adaptive-threshold

I am developing an app for iOS with openCV that take a picture from a monitor and extract a curve, but when the image has some bright zones after thresholding, I don't get the complete curve but some black zones

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1voq.jpg)

[processed image after thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBi4w.jpg)

```
        original = [MAOpenCV cvMatGrayFromUIImage:_sourceImage];   
        cv::threshold(original, original, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

        findContours(original, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

        cv::Mat skel(original.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

        int idx = 0;
        for(; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
        {
            if (contours[idx].size()>250 && idx>-1){
                cv::Scalar color( 255,255,255);
                drawContours(skel, contours, idx, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy);
            }
        }
        cv::threshold(skel, skel, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        cv::erode(skel,skel,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),2);
```

So how I can process the image to extract the curve when the image have some bright zones like the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a background with an uneven illumination, you may want to apply first a White [Top-Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-hat_transform) (or [here for MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtophat.html), and [here for OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)).

[Here is the result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/k1voqWTH.png) I got using a structuring element of type disk with radius 3.

Then, whatever thresholding method you choose will work.

Comment: I get a black image when I apply this code:              cv::morphologyEx(imgColor, imgColor2, cv::MORPH_TOPHAT, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,cv::Size(3,3))); can you give me an example, thank you!!

Comment: I don't use OpenCV, but maybe you are performing a black top-hat. A white top-hat is: Image - Opening(Image). Try this version.

Comment: It worked, but increasing the kernel size to > 16, thanks

Comment: using a RECT element make the process faster

Comment: It's normal because a rectangle can be decomposed into two segments, so you drop the complexity. 16 seems surprisingly big for this images, but maybe you have other images that require such by SE.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be sufficient to use Otsu's thresholding?
[image: Otsu's thresholding result]

Code fragment:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('d:/so.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

threshold, thresholded = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
print(threshold)

cv2.imshow('so', image);
cv2.imshow('thresholded', thresholded)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I already use Otsu, but how you see the curve is still noisy in the bright spots